# I switched to 12.10 and my wine - adobe digital editions stuff stopped working

Tags: 12.10, wine, adobe

I switched to 12.10 and my wine - adobe digital editions stuff stopped working. I un-installed wine and reinstalled wine1.5. Now what to do about adobe digital editions? I have deleted and re-installed adobe digital editions and it appears to run, however it no longer shows my nook. I tried the wine configuration tool to set the nook to be a floppy disk but after I apply and OK when I re-open the wine tool the selection for the nook has reverted to autodetect. Has anyone got around this new problem? If I leave the wine configuration pane open I can see the Nook, but when I OK and close the wine pane the selection doesn't stick.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may seem like a very dumb answer, but instead of clicking OK have you tried clicking apply? As far as I can tell you did it right.

Comment: Yes I make sure to click apply first. Then if I leave the wine configuration tool open the Nook appears in Adobe Digital Editions and every thing is cool. The minute I click OK in the wine tool, it closes and the Nook disappears from Adobe DE.